# Azure Devops Comment for better Visualization

Tags: azure, devops, metabase

The problem here is we are not able to view comments posted in the discussion on Azure Devops and extract and validate these artefacts which are created on BI tool metabase

We are expecting comments in a structured format for better visualization To extract and validate artefacts or else if we can add a link which can directly take us to that comment on azure Devops

Please refer below snippet of the metabase report which supports visualization and analytics

we would want these comments to be readable to validate further on analytics tool

Please suggest